# Firebase: Child event listener seems to reload all data on every child added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database node called `posts`, looks like this:

```
    posts
    |
    |---post1
    |
    |---post2
    |
    |---post3
```

post 1,2,3 are push ids. Its basically a node that stores the posts as push ids which means they are automatically added from top to bottom, bottom being the new added posts.

To listen to this node I attached a child event listener to get all the posts, when I get the posts I store them in a List object (array). Now to keep track of the size of the list I added a log statement. like this:

```java
private void getPosts() {
    DatabaseReference post_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
    Query query = post_ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(25);
    ChildEventListener listener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot datasnapshot , String s) {
            //get posts
            Post post = datasnapshot.getValue(Post.class);

            //add to list
            post_list.add(post);

            //log the size of post_list
            Log.e("SIZE" , String.valueOf(post_list.size()));
        } 
    };
    
    query.addChildEventListener(listener); 
}
```

After doing this the log printed a list of numbers that starts at `1` and ends at `25`. Which indicates that the child event listener was called 25 times and 25 objects where added to the list.

until here all makes sense.

**Problem**

After I called `getPosts()` method. I added a new post to the database and the console printed `25`, which means that the size is still 25. But I just added a new post which mean that it should have been added to the list.

I should get `26` as the new size, so why it is still `25`?

Also when I add another and another post the size of `post_list` still logs `25`. So can someone explain that?

Comment: Did you check if the values in you list have changed (probably the first and/or last item)?

Comment: You are doing `limitToLast(25)`, and still asking why you only get 25?

Answer (score 0):

You just receive only 25 objects, becaused you set 
 `Query query = post_ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(25);`

Please read Google Firebase document

```
The limitToLast() method is used to set a maximum number of children to be synced for a given callback. If we set a limit of 100, we will initially only receive up to 100 child_added events. If we have fewer than 100 messages stored in our Database, a child_added event will fire for each message. However, if we have over 100 messages, we will only receive a child_added event for the last 100 ordered messages. As items change, we will receive child_removed events for each item that drops out of the active list so that the total number stays at 100.
```

This is link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Answer (score -1):

Since you have used **[`limitToLast()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToLast)**, You are getting this issue.

It is used to **`set a maximum number of children`** to be synced for a given callback.

If you set a limit of 25, you will initially only receive up to 25 child_added events.

However, if you have over 25 messages, you will only receive a child_added event for the last 25 ordered messages. As items change, you will receive child_removed events for each item that drops out of the active list so that **`the total number stays at 25.`**

Comment: But why the post list still have a size of 25? the first 25 are in the list .....but after I added a new post why the post  did not add up with rest items in the list?

Comment: because you are setting the limit as 25. When you are adding 26th element ,it will be dropped. The query will add only 25 items. add onChildRemoved() method to get more idea

Comment: Okay I understand but what about post_list? If I first attach the listener then the list has 25 items......now without touching the list.......If I add a new item then the child added gets called with a new item and that item should be added to the list.....but keep in mind that the list already had 25.......so with 1 more it should be 26.

Comment: why the list is keeping a constant size.....if it is not being touched?

Comment: the document clearly says ,if you add more than a limit, you will receive child_removed event. So the post_list will only have 25 items.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But if I didn't call post_list.remove(removed_post), how come the post_list is still having fixed size....I don't think you understand what I am asking about.

Comment: I understand.  `Log.e("SIZE" , String.valueOf(post_list.size()));`  it prints **SIZE : 25**  when you added the 26th item??? I did get any idea. let me check.

Comment: First time child listener 25 times, this will store 25 children in the list......now when I added a new item this means that child listener will run once and will add the 26th item......so it doesn't matter what dropped here ..... the thing that matters is why the size of the list is still 25 every single time.....Any way thanks for your help and time.